# Metaclasses and when/how functions are called

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, metaclass

I'm trying to learn how metaclasses work in python 3. Things I want to know are: which functions are called, in what order, and their signatures and returns.

As an example, I know `__prepare__` gets called when a class with a metaclass is instantiated with arguments `metaclass, name_of_subclass, bases` and returns a dictionary representing the future namespace of the instantiated object.

I feel like I understand `__prepare__`'s step in the process well. What I don't, though, are `__init__`, `__new__`, and `__call__`. What are their arguments? What do they return? How do they all call each other, or in general how does the process go? Currently, I'm stuck on understanding when `__init__` is called.

Here is some code I've been messing around with to answer my questions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Logged(type):

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(cls, name, bases):
        print('In meta __prepare__')
        return {}

    def __call__(subclass):
        print('In meta __call__')
        print('Creating {}.'.format(subclass))
        return subclass.__new__(subclass)

    def __new__(subclass, name, superclasses, attributes, **keyword_arguments):
        print('In meta __new__')
        return type.__new__(subclass, name, superclasses, attributes)

    def __init__(subclass, name, superclasses, attributes, **keyword_arguments):
        print('In meta __init__')

class Thing(metaclass = Logged):

    def __new__(this, *arguments, **keyword_arguments):
        print('In sub __new__')
        return super(Thing, this).__new__(this)

    def __init__(self, *arguments, **keyword_arguments):
        print('In sub __init__')

    def hello(self):
        print('hello')

def main():
    thing = Thing()
    thing.hello()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

From this and some googling, I know that `__new__` is really a static method that returns an instance of some object (usually the object where `__new__` is defined, but not always), and that `__init__` is called of an instance when it is made. By that logic, I'm confused as to why `Thing.__init__()` isn't being called. Could someone illuminate?

The output of this code prints 'hello', so an instance of Thing is being created, which further confuses me about init. Here's the output:

```
In meta __prepare__
In meta __new__
In meta __init__
In meta __call__
Creating <class '__main__.Thing'>
In sub __new__
hello
```

Any help understanding metaclasses would be appreciated. I've read quite a few tutorials, but I've missed some of these details.

Comment: `__new__` is not a static method; it's a *class* method that is special-cased so that you don't have to decorate it with `@classmethod`.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the nuance differences, but I believe you're right @chepner. That's what I meant to get to, more-or-less.

Comment: Class methods receive the invoking class as its first argument; static methods do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: `__prepare__` is optional, you don't need to supply an implementation if all you are doing is return a default `{}` empty dictionary.

Metaclasses work *exactly like classes*, in that when you call them, then they produce an object. Both classes and metaclasses are *factories*. The difference is that a metaclass produces a class object when called, a class produces an instance when called.

Both classes and metaclasses define a default `__call__` implementation, which basically does:

1. Call `self.__new__` to produce a new object.
2. if that new object is an instance of self / a class with this
   metaclass, then *also* call `__init__` on that object.

You produced your own `__call__` implementation, which doesn't implement that second step, which is why `Thing.__init__` is never called.

You may ask: *but the `__call__` method is defined on the metaclass*. That's correct, so it is *exactly that method* that is called when you call the class with `Thing()`. All special methods (starting and ending with `__`) are [called on the type](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) (e.g. `type(instance)` is the class, and `type(class)` is the metaclass) precisely because Python has this multi-level hierarchy of instances from classes from metaclasses; a `__call__` method on the class itself is used to make instances callable. For `metaclass()` calls, it is the `type` object itself that provides the `__call__` implementation. That's right, metaclasses are both subclasses and instances of `type`, at the same time.

When writing a metaclass, you should only implement `__call__` if you want to customise what happens when you call the class. Leave it at the default implementation otherwise.

If I remove the `__call__` method from your metaclass (and ignore the `__prepare__` method), then `Thing.__init__` is once again called:

```
>>> class Logged(type):
...     def __new__(subclass, name, superclasses, attributes, **keyword_arguments):
...         print('In meta __new__')
...         return type.__new__(subclass, name, superclasses, attributes)
...     def __init__(subclass, name, superclasses, attributes, **keyword_arguments):
...         print('In meta __init__')
...
>>> class Thing(metaclass = Logged):
...     def __new__(this, *arguments, **keyword_arguments):
...         print('In sub __new__')
...         return super(Thing, this).__new__(this)
...     def __init__(self, *arguments, **keyword_arguments):
...         print('In sub __init__')
...     def hello(self):
...         print('hello')
...
In meta __new__
In meta __init__
>>> thing = Thing()
In sub __new__
In sub __init__
```

Comment: The output of your answer at the end really brought to light what was going on, supported by the rest of your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the metaclass's `__call__` method, you're calling `Thing`'s `__new__` only, but not `__init__`. It seems that the default behaviour of `__call__` is to invoke both of them, as seen when we call the metaclass's inherited `__call__`:

```
    def __call__(subclass):
        print('In meta __call__')
        print('Creating {}.'.format(subclass))
        return super().__call__(subclass)
```

This prints:

```
Creating <class '__main__.Thing'>.
In sub __new__
In sub __init__
```

Comment: You've got it; `type.__call__()` calls `__new__()` first, then calls `__init__()` if `__new__()` returned an instance of the class. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely the crux of my immediate problem. I wish it was possible to pick two answers, since Martin answered more questions, because you're answer truly helped me fix my problem quickly.