# __new__, __init__, and metaclasses (and superclasses)

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, metaprogramming, metaclass

I've been spending the day trying to understand the intricacies of the python class model, messing around with decorators, metaclasses, and superclasses.

Currently, I'm trying to figure out the role of certain token functions, namely **new** (back-story here [Metaclasses and when/how functions are called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628756/metaclasses-and-when-how-functions-are-called))

I've made a new mock-up module to run tests in, here:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys as system
import os  as operating_system

from functools import partial
from time      import perf_counter as counter

class Meta(type):

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(instance, name, supers, *list, **map):
        print('{} in meta prepare'.format(name))
        return {}

    def __new__(instance, name, supers, attributes, *list, **map):
        print('{} in meta new'.format(name))
        return instance

    def __init__(self, name, supers, attributes, *list, **map):
            print('{} in meta init'.format(self))

    def __call__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in meta call'.format(self))
        return type.__call__(self)
        print('after call')

class Super(object):

    def __new__(instance, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Super new'.format(instance))
        return instance

    def __init__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Super init'.format(self))

    def __call__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Super call'.format(self))
        return object.__call__(self)

class Other(object):

    def __new__(instance, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Other new'.format(instance))
        return instance

    def __init__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Other init'.format(self))

    def __call__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Other call'.format(self))
        return object.__call__(self)

class MetaSuper(object, metaclass = Meta):

    def __new__(instance, *list, **map):
        print('{} in MetaSuper new'.format(instance))
        return instance

    def __init__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in MetaSuper init'.format(self))

    def __call__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in MetaSuper call'.format(self))
        return object.__call__(self)

class DoubleSuper(Super, MetaSuper):

    def __new__(instance, *list, **map):
        print('{} in DoubleSuper new'.format(instance))
        return instance

    def __init__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in DoubleSuper init'.format(self))
        Super.__init__(self, *list, **map)
        MetaSuper.__init__(self, *list, **map)

    def __call__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in DoubleSuper call'.format(self))
        return object.__call__(self)

class SuperThenMeta(Super, metaclass = Meta):

    def __new__(instance, *list, **map):
        print('{} in SuperThenMeta new'.format(instance))
        return instance

    def __init__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in SuperThenMeta init'.format(self))
        Super.__init__(self, *list, **map)

    def __call__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in SuperThenMeta call'.format(self))
        return object.__call__(self)

class Triple(Super, Other, metaclass = Meta):

    def __new__(instance, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Triple new'.format(instance))
        return instance

    def __init__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Triple init'.format(self))
        Super.__init__(self, *list, **map)
        Other.__init__(self, *list, **map)

    def __call__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Triple call'.format(self))
        return object.__call__(self)

class Simple(Super):

    def __new__(instance, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Simple new'.format(instance))
        return instance.__init__(instance, *list, **map)

    def __init__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Simple init'.format(self))
        Super.__init__(self, *list, **map)
        Other.__init__(self, *list, **map)

    def __call__(self, *list, **map):
        print('{} in Simple call'.format(self))
        return object.__call__(self)    

def main():
    #thing = SuperThenMeta()
    #other = DoubleSuper()
    last  = Super()
    simp  = Simple()
    trip  = Triple()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

TL;DR, I experimented with a few different setups between these working pieces.

If I run this, this is the output:

```
MetaSuper in meta prepare
MetaSuper in meta new
SuperThenMeta in meta prepare
SuperThenMeta in meta new
Triple in meta prepare
Triple in meta new
<class '__main__.Super'> in Super new
<class '__main__.Simple'> in Simple new
<class '__main__.Simple'> in Simple init
<class '__main__.Simple'> in Super init
<class '__main__.Simple'> in Other init
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./metaprogramming.py", line 134, in <module>
  main()
File "./metaprogramming.py", line 131, in main
  trip = Triple()
TypeError: __new__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'name', 'supers', and 'attributes'
```

From this, I have a few questions:

- Am I supposed to be calling instance.**init**(instance, *list, **map) at the end of **new** functions? I didn't think so, but adding that into the 'Simple' example seemed to work, while 'Super' never reached its **init**. I was under the impression that by calling object.**call** in my own call methods, this would be handled by it's default implementation, but no __call__s are made during the whole program.
- Why is calling Triple() calling the metaclasses **new** first? If this is normal, does that mean this is typical of any class with a metaclass? Is this similar behavior to superclasses?
- I expected **call** to be in this list somewhere. Does it not get called during the creation routine of objects (eg [prepare], new, init)?

I know this is a lot of information, so thank you for reading this far; any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to think `__new__` takes the new instance as its first argument. It doesn't; that argument is the class. `__new__` is supposed to *create* the new instance, usually by calling `super().__new__`.

Comment: I think most of your problems are consequences of that misunderstanding.

Comment: Call is what runs new and init. Doing `X()` invokes object `X`'s `__call__` method no matter what since that's just what the operator does. Actually it's `type(X).__call__(X)`

Comment: @user2357112 I had no idea. Thank you! I will fix my code with that in mind, by calling the super, and probably returning what it returns.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, that's what I thought, but then I can't explain why no prints in the call methods printed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Metaclass' `__new__`

The method `__new__` is what is called to create a new instance. Thus its first argument *is not* an instance, since none has been created yet, but rather the class itself.

In the case of a metaclass, `__new__` is expected to return an instance of your metaclass, that is a *class*. It's signature goes like this:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        ...
```

- `metacls` is the metaclass itself.
- `name` is a string representing the name of the class being
  instantiated.
- `bases` is a tuple of classes from which the class will inherit.
- `namespace` is the namespace of the class, this is the object
  returned by `__prepare__`, now populated with the class attributes.
- `**kwargs` are any keyword arguments passed to the class at instantiation

To instantiate a class, you need to call `type.__new__`, which is the default metaclass. You usually do that by calling `super().__new__`.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        print('You can do stuff here')

        cls = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

        # You must return the generated class
        return cls
```

## Metaclass' `__init__`

The `__init__` method behaves the same as for any other class. It receives the created instance, here a class, as argument if `__new__` returned an instance of the expected type. In your example, `__new__` does not return an object of type `Meta`. It return `Meta` itself which is of type `type`.

The following `__init__` method is never called on instantiation.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        return None # or anything such that type(obj) is not Meta
    
    def __init__(self, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        # This will never be called because the return type of `__new__` is wrong
        pass
```

The following is called on instantiation, because `Meta.__new__` correctly returns an object of type `Meta`.

```
class Meta(type):
        def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
            return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
        
        def __init__(self, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
            print('__init__ was called')
```

## Metaclass' `__call__`

Again, the behaviour of `__call__` is no different than for any other class. It is called when you try to call an *instance* of the metaclass, while `__new__` and `__init__` are called when you called the *metaclass* to create an instance (a class).

Of course, calling a class is expected to return an instance, so do not forget to call `super().__call__` and return its result, otherwise you would be short-circuiting the instance creation, as it is `type.__call__` which calls `__new__` and `__init__`.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'An instance was called with {args}')
        return super().__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

# This declaration if what calls __new__ and __init__ of the metaclass
class Klass(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

# This calls the __call__ method of the metaclass
instance = Klass()
```

Comment: A metaclass `__new__` is also supposed to take `**kwargs`, even if just to forward them to `super().__new__`. Also, if you write a metaclass `__init__` (usually a bad idea - metaclasses should perform initialization in `__new__`), it should take name, bases, namespace, and kwargs too.

Comment: As for `__init__`, why would that be? In the above example it is called after `__new__` as expected

Comment: For passing kwargs to the metaclass: `super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)`. For `__init__`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/Y4fhId) of `__init__` needing more arguments than you declared it with.

Comment: @user2357112 You are correct, I forgot arguments in the `__init__` signature. Although, I see no reason why calling `__init__` should be done inside `__new__`. As for the kwargs, I disagree as `type.__new__` does not take keyword arguments.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. You pass kwargs through the parameter list of the class: `class A(base1, ..., baseN, kwarg1=value1, ..., kwargN=valueN)`

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. The fact that `type.__new__` does not accept kwargs is not a reason not to allow them in the general case. Many classes accept arguments to `__new__` despite the fact that `object.__new__` does not.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh wow... I did not know we could do that. That's neat! Although, for this particular example I see no reason why we should include unused kwargs.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well... I see some cases of multiple inheritance where that could serve, so I will add them.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: I didn't say to call `__init__` inside `__new__`. As for kwargs, `type.__new__` actually does take keyword arguments, which it forwards to `__init_subclass__`. For your metaclass to be compatible with `__init_subclass__`, it has to take `**kwargs` and forward them to `super().__new__` to maintain the chain. ([There have been problems](https://bugs.python.org/issue29581) when standard library metaclasses didn't perform this forwarding.)

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. I agree that it would be overkill for this discussion. But yeah, in Python 3, `metaclass` itself is one of those arguments, but it gets special handling. It won't crash your meta-new even if it doesn't accept kwargs.