# Understanding class creation with __init__ and __new__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand the methods `__new__` and `__init__`. I know, that `__new__` creates a new object and `__init__` initializes the object with values. What I don't understand is who is calling the methods and how can I manipulate values ​​so that the `__init__` function is called with the changed values. My example code is the following:

```
class Point:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, x, y, kw = False):
        self._x  = x
        self._y  = y
        self._kw = kw

class BigPoint(Point):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, [2300, 7800], **kwargs)

bp = BigPoint(1000, 1000, kw = True)
print(bp.__dict__)
```

If I call in `BigPoint` the `Point`'s `__new__` method with the manipulated values, I don't see any differences. Even if I change the code

```
class Point:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        p = super().__new__(cls)
        p._x = 2300
        return p
    ...
```

the result is still the same. Who is calling the `__init__` method and with what parameters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_new\_\_, \_\_init\_\_, and metaclasses (and superclasses)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635635/new-init-and-metaclasses-and-superclasses)

Comment: it happens in the metaclass `__call__`, in this case, in `type.__call__`

Comment: Please **always** use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. Since Python 2 is passed it's official end of life, really, generic python tag implies Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by `type.__call__`, which is the default metaclass.

In Python, all objects, including class objects, are instances of a class themselves. Metaclasses are just classes that create classes. The default metaclass is `type`.

`__call__` is the method that controls how callables behave. A class object is a callable that (typically) returns an instance of itself (and instance of the class)

Here is a [link to the source on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d0160c7c22c8dff0a61c49b5304244df6e36465e/Objects/typeobject.c#L1648), where `type.__call__` is implemented in C:

The meat of it occurs here, after some bookkeeping and the handling a special case:

```c
    obj = type->tp_new(type, args, kwds);
    obj = _Py_CheckFunctionResult(tstate, (PyObject*)type, obj, NULL);
    if (obj == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* If the returned object is not an instance of type,
       it won't be initialized. */
    if (!PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, type))
        return obj;

    type = Py_TYPE(obj);
    if (type->tp_init != NULL) {
        int res = type->tp_init(obj, args, kwds);
        if (res < 0) {
            assert(_PyErr_Occurred(tstate));
            Py_SETREF(obj, NULL);
        }
        else {
            assert(!_PyErr_Occurred(tstate));
        }
    }
    return obj;
```

So, if you wanted to customize this behavior, you could implement you own metaclass and override `__call__`:

```py
class MyMeta(type):
    def __call__(typ, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

class Big point(Point, metaclass=MyMeta):
    ...
```

But frankly, In the example you seem to have (which I guess may just be a toy example) this is not the way to go. This should just be handled in in `BigPoint.__init__`

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self):
```

initializes the attributes of a class.

```
def __new__(...):
```

creates a new instance of a class.

When you create a new object of a class, python first call **new** then **init**.

Here **init** is called automatically when **new** returns an new instance with the first args initialised, that's overriding the changes you are trying to make on **new**.